# Hiding and showing fields depending on other field values with z3c.form and Plone

Tags: schema, plone, dexterity

im creating a content type in plone using dexterity.. so far so good.. but i want to create a Schema.Bool that when its check it hides some fields. here is my sample

```
sameaddress = schema.Bool(
        title=_(u"Sames as bill to address"),
        required=False,
    )

toCustShipStreet = schema.TextLine(
        title=_(u"Ship to - Street:"),
    )

toCustShipCity = schema.TextLine(
        title=_(u"Ship to - City:"),
    )
toCustShipState = schema.TextLine(
        title=_(u"Ship to - State:"),
    )
toCustShipCountry = schema.TextLine(
        title=_(u"Ship to - Country:"),
    )
```

how can i do this?? please help

Answer (score 2):

I am doing this with Plone sites using this my little JavaScript library:

https://github.com/miohtama/jquery-interdependencies

- Embed deps.js as JavaScript resource
- Create a controller file which defines rules what widgets the boolean field hides and whatnot (this is not actually Plone specific, you can throw in any CSS ids)
- Make sure the logic gets fired up every time the correct page loads

Example `widget-rules.js` (I cannot provide complete example for confidentiality reasons, but this should give you some pointers):

```
/*global console*/

(function($) {

    "use strict";


    // jQuery selector for all possible different stenosis fields (CR, MR, treatment)
    var stenosisFields = "#formfield-thrombectomyVariables-widgets-thrombectomyVariables_treatmentSpecifylocalizationOfStenosis";

    function log(msg) {
        if(console && console.log) {
            console.log(msg);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Generate datagridfield block jQuery class selection based on field name.
     *
     * Note that the same field will appear multiple times on the page.
     */
    function getDGFId(fname) {
        return ".datagridwidget-widget-" + fname;
    }


    function buildRules() {

        // Start creating a new ruleset
        var ruleset = $.deps.createRuleset();

        var masterSwitch = ruleset.createRule("#typeOfStenosisOcclusion") + " select", "==", "other");

        // Make this controls to be slave for the master rule
        masterSwitch.include("#typeOfStenosisOcclusionWhich");

        return ruleset;
    }

    function init() {

        // Master field containing all MTD rows
        var fields = $(stenosisFields);

        if(fields.size() > 0) {
            var ruleset = buildRules();
            initRules($this, ruleset);
            followRules($this, ruleset);
        }

    }

    $(document).bind("ready", init);

})(jQuery);
```